# Can I use Angular2 Router.navigate to navigate to a url with ID midway through route

Tags: angular, routes, angular-router

I've got a route working with

```
this.router.navigate(["/approvals", id]);
```

which navigates to `/approvals/[id]`

I'm wondering how I can route to `/approvals/[id]/users`

Does anyone know?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.router.navigate(["/approvals", id, "users"])`